# MUI X DatePicker formatting and setting default value issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

I am having a bit of an issue, and I've had not much luck finding a solution to it.
The MUI X DatePicker (with Material UI) seems to have a format that it has as a default, for displaying the dates as

```
Fri Oct dd yyyy HH:MM:SS GMT+HHMM (name of timezone here)
```

However, I need to be able to pass a date in the format of

`yyyy-MM-ddThh:MM:ss+HH:mm` which is `(Date)T(Time)+(Timezone)`

to the component, and then back to be submitted in the same format.

In some cases, the value for this date-time-picker is not set, in some cases it is. And I'm not sure how to get the format to what I need it, since I have no control of the date-format I am receiving.

It seems the component can parse the data I give it, and set the proper value, but the new data (if the value changes) does is in a different format.

edit: Just a quick example for above.

```
Data I get: 2020-10-11T15:56:28+11:00
```

Data the component outputs: `{ "$L": "en", "$u": undefined, "$d": Date Sun Oct 11 2020 15:56:28 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time), "$x": {}, "$y": 2020, "$M": 9, "$D": 11, "$W": 0, "$H": 15, "$m": 56, … }`

Relevant code for DateTimePicker:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import DateTimePicker from '@mui/lab/DateTimePicker';

export default function DateTimePickerComponent(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
    const onDatePicked = (event) => {
        setValue(event);
        let onlyDate = event.$d;
        props.onChange(onlyDate);
        console.log("Date Changed", event, onlyDate);
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (props.initialValue !== 0 && value === null) {
            setValue(props.initialValue);
            console.log("Initial Date is", props.initialValue);
        }
    }, [props.initialValue, value, setValue]);

    return (
        <DateTimePicker
            label={props.label}
            value={value}
            onChange={onDatePicked}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: I went about a different way to solve it. After doing some research, someone pointed me at the fact that it was already in a date format, just parsed differently by MUI.

Answer (score 6):

After doing some research, I was pointed to the fact that MUI's DatePicker/DateTimePicker uses a basic date format (as it formulated it in the event call). However, MUI parses and displays it differently, so all I had to do was simply the following:

```
let onlyDate = event.$d.toISOString();
```

this returned the date-time string I needed in the proper format.

If anyone comes across this in the future, look at this page I had ended up at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

It has multiple ways of parsing the data and functions to manipulate the date/time

Answer (score 5):

To format the date, use `inputFormat` prop. If you're using date-fns, you can see the [this table](https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/format) to know how to customize the format string:

```
<DateTimePicker
  label={props.label}
  value={value}
  inputFormat="E MMM dd yyyy HH:MM:SS O"
  onChange={setValue}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} fullWidth />}
/>
```

If you want to set the initial value in a component that uses controlled mode, you must initialize the it in `useState`:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialDate);
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar issue by setting value to mui MUI Datepicker using dayjs library

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'; 
 
<DateTimePicker
label={props.label}
value={dayjs(value)}
onChange={onDatePicked}
renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
/>
```